# How do I make truncate log script as dynamic SQL in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using the below script to truncate the log files of a database. But I have to execute the below script results in separate window due to this I am not able to schedule the jobs .

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 

SELECT 
      'USE [' + d.name + N']' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
    + 'DBCC SHRINKFILE (N''' + mf.name + N''' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)' 
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
FROM 
         sys.master_files mf 
    JOIN sys.databases d 
        ON mf.database_id = d.database_id 
WHERE d.database_id > 4 and mf.type_desc = 'LOG'
```

Expected O/P is script has to run instead of copy pasting the above query results

Comment: An alternative to dynamic SQL is to use SQL Server's Maintenance Plans.  Each plan is an SSIS package executed by the SQL Agent, on a fixed scheduled.  Here is a link to the [MS Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187658.aspx).

Comment: If you can't use maintenance plans...Are you looking for something as simple as [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)? You would use this in conjunction with a cursor.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with Dynamic SQL, without using a `cursor`:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL +
      'USE [' + d.name + N']' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
    + 'DBCC SHRINKFILE (N''' + mf.name + N''' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY);' 
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
FROM 
         sys.master_files mf 
    JOIN sys.databases d 
        ON mf.database_id = d.database_id 
WHERE d.database_id > 4 and mf.type_desc = 'LOG'

PRINT   (@SQL)
EXEC    (@SQL)
```

Does the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @LOG TABLE (
  QUERY varchar(max)
)
DECLARE @QUERY varchar(max)

INSERT INTO @LOG
  SELECT
    'USE [' + d.name + N']' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + 'DBCC SHRINKFILE (N''' + mf.name + N''' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)'
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
  FROM sys.master_files mf
  JOIN sys.databases d
    ON mf.database_id = d.database_id
  WHERE d.database_id > 4
  AND mf.type_desc = 'LOG'


DECLARE C CURSOR FOR
SELECT
  QUERY
FROM @LOG
OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @QUERY
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  PRINT @QUERY
  EXEC (@QUERY)
  FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @QUERY
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
```

Comment: Hi , I am not able vote but Ranjana Ghimire script worked for me. Thanks Ranjana.

Comment: You are welcome. no problem about voting. I am glad that i could help you.

Comment: please mark this question as answered (without voting) to help people when they search no this topic