# looping through Comma Separated Values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to loop through each value present in the variable **@columnNames** and use it in a dynamic sql. Below is the code.

```
DECLARE @columnNames NVARCHAR(MAX), @dSql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SEt @columnNames = 'SCHEDULEDSTART, SCHEDULEDEND'

WHILE (LEN(@columnNames) > 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT left(@columnNames, charindex(',', @columnNames+',')-1)
    print @columnNames
    SET @dSql = 'ALTER TABLE NAMS.AssetActivity ALTER COLUMN ' + @columnNames + ' DATETIME2(7)'
    PRINT (@dSql)
    set @columnNames = stuff(@columnNames, 1, charindex(',', @columnNames+','), '')
END
```

In the output the 1st query is messed up. The output that I'm getting is listed below:

```
(1 row affected)
ALTER TABLE NAMS.AssetActivity ALTER COLUMN SCHEDULEDSTART, SCHEDULEDEND DATETIME2(7)

(1 row affected)
ALTER TABLE NAMS.AssetActivity ALTER COLUMN  SCHEDULEDEND DATETIME2(7)
```

A help is going to be very much appreciated. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: What is your expected results?

Comment: Because your logic is wrong. You append your variable to the <alter table> string, not the expression based on finding the comma.

Comment: And 2005 does not support datetime2 - and i doubt 2008 does as well.

Comment: 2008 introduced the new date and time datatypes, @SMor , however, *both* 2005 and 2008 are **completely** unsupported and the OP should be urgently looking at upgrade paths.

Comment: As for splitting, looping is the worst way to go about it. I *think* 2005 supported XML splitters, however, 2008 certainly does and supports `delimitedsplit8k` (Google it); both are *far* better solutions. but the *real* solution here is fix your model and don't use delimited data. Also, depending where the value of `@columnNames` is coming from, this is wide open to injection.

Comment: @Birel My expected Result is: (1 row affected)
ALTER TABLE NAMS.AssetActivity ALTER COLUMN SCHEDULEDSTART DATETIME2(7)

(1 row affected)
ALTER TABLE NAMS.AssetActivity ALTER COLUMN  SCHEDULEDEND DATETIME2(7)

Comment: @SMor I'm using SQL Server 2014

Comment: @SMor Thanks for identifying the error in the logic. I've fixed it now.

Comment: See a similar answer I provided previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60277663/7740387) @AritraSarkar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to Garbriele's answer, your script would have to look like this:

```
DECLARE
    @columnNames    NVARCHAR(MAX)
,   @dSql           NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @columnNames = 'SCHEDULEDSTART, SCHEDULEDEND'

SELECT
    @dSql = @dSql + 'ALTER TABLE NAMS.AssetActivity ALTER COLUMN ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Value)) + ' DATETIME2(7)'+char(10)
FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@columnNames, ',')

PRINT   (@dSql)
--EXEC  (@dSql)
```

Which gives you the following results:

[image: Results]

See [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b5223a2ef1bbc65e47f49db767dec074)

Answer (score 2):

From SQL Server 2017 you can use STRING SPLIT function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15